# Html.DropDownListFor default selected value does not work

Tags: html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

I have read hundreds of posts about this problem and I still can't find a solution.

Please help with this horrible mistery;

I would like to have different default values in my DropDownListFor. The "PartialViewList1 exists out of 4 items.
I want the DropDownListFor to select the id of the current item. (item.id)

But because of testing purposes I just filled in "3". And even that doesn't work.

The Models are filled correctly, I am able to add more code of the controller but that wouldn't add much. But please ask if you want me to.

And yes I know that it is better to make the SelectList in the controller, but first I want to make it work.

View:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.PartialViewList1)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>Plaats: </td>
            <td>@item.PlaceNumber</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PartialView.Id, new SelectList(Model.PartialViewList2, "Id", "Name", 3),
                new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

[Screen shot of the users view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gSpg.png)

Comment: Its the value of `PartialView.Id` that determines what is selected (that is how model binding works - it **binds** to the value of your property (the last paramater of the `SelectList` constructor is ignored when binding to a property). But your code makes no sense - your generating multiple dropdownlists for the same property so its not clear what you trying to do here

Comment: I have 4 partialviews on one screen. I want the user to be able to change the partialview per available place on the screen. So I am using "PartialViewList1" to get the PlaceNumber per partialview. And I am using "PartialViewList2" to get the names of the partialviews.

But I found what you said on this page: https://nimblegecko.com/how-to-set-default-selected-value-on-drop-down-list-from-database/
under the paragraph: "DANGER. WARNING. THERE BE DRAGONS."

Comment: Yes by why are you generating 4 dropdownlists? And they all bind to the same property which makes no sense

Comment: Ah I get what you're thinking. 4 dropdownlists all bind to id of the same partialview object. 
My thought was when I change 1 dropdownlist then it will submit with only that partialview object (and load the page again). So every time I change something it will be submitted at once. So correct me if I am wrong but it should work like that right? Because my controller does get the right id's.

Comment: There are a few problems with that. For example, you will not get any validation except on the first one. In any case, making a submit on the change of a form control is a bad UI (it is not the expected behavior - and consider what happens when users use the arrow keys to scroll through the options). Have a button to make the submit so the user can check what they have selected first. But I still do not understand why you need 4 dropdownlists that all show identical options and are bound to the one property

Comment: I have added a image for you to understand what I am doing ( what probably is wrong ) I am sorry, i am not that experienced.
I now made 4 different dropdownlistfors and binded them to different properties ( PartialView1.Id, PartialView2.Id etc..)
At this moment the default value id's do work. So that double binding does seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that maybe someone can use this for his or her problem.

With Stephen Mueke I have found the solution. The problem is that if "x => x.PartialView.Id" already has a value then the default value : "3" will be overriden by the Id.

And you can't generate multiple DropDownlistFor's while binding them to the same property.

My solution on my problem:

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("_PartialSettingsDropDownList1", "Home")){
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.maxNumberOfViews; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                Plaats @(i+1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.PartialViewList[i].ID, new SelectList(Model.PartialViewList, "Id", "Name", Model.PartialViewList[i].ID), "select")
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.maxNumberOfViews)

<input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult _PartialSettingsDropDownList1()
    {
        PartialScreenViewModel viewModel = new PartialScreenViewModel();
        viewModel.PartialViewList = homeModel.AllBoxViews(databaseRepository.PartialViews);
        viewModel.maxNumberOfViews = viewModel.PartialViewList.Count();

        return PartialView(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public RedirectResult _PartialSettingsDropDownList1(PartialScreenViewModel viewModel)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < viewModel.maxNumberOfViews; i++)
        {
            PartialView viewOnScreen = databaseRepository.PartialViews.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == viewModel.PartialViewList[i].ID);
            databaseRepository.UpdatePartialView(viewOnScreen, i+1);
        }

        return new RedirectResult("Settings");
    }
```

Model:

```
    public List<PartialView> AllBoxViews(IEnumerable<PartialView> allViews)
    {
        List<PartialView> OnlyBoxViews = new List<PartialView>();
        foreach (var item in allViews.Where(item => item.Type.Equals("box")))
        {
            OnlyBoxViews.Add(item);
        }

        return OnlyBoxViews;
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class PartialScreenViewModel
{
    public List<PartialView> PartialViewList { get; set; }
    public int maxNumberOfViews { get; set; }
}
```

Result on screen: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jeqp.png)